# Android R.java Cannot be Resolved Without Full Path

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

As you can see from the capture. My **ALL** projects' `R.java` file cannot be resolved if i dont import full path of my `R.java` but yesterday when i was doing somethings only `android.R` was enough to resolve. What is the problem? I cleaned my projects 5-6 times. Restart pc and Eclipse. Problem is the same. What can cause to this?

`android.R` -> cannot be resolved

`com.example.helloWorld.R` works good

[image]

Comment: check and make sure all of your assets are named properly. I had this happen when I had a mp3 file whose name started with a number

Comment: @JustinV. is it not related with assets. All things comes from `R.java` cannot be resolved if i import only `android.R` but if i import full path of my project's `R.java` file it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.R` -> Android internal resources file. You don't want to import that.

The R.java file is used to store resource ids. `android.R` stores, like said, framework resources. `com.example.helloWorld.R` is the R.java file for your resource Ids.

Comment: Can't be. Have you maybe cleaned your imports with cmd/Ctrl + O? Eclipse tends to import that.

Comment: Yes i used **Ctrl** + **O** for automatic import/Del

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem then.

Comment: Be sure that you build your project before cleaning the imports. This should ensure that Eclipse can find the `R` class in your project so that it won't import `android.R` for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use `android.R` explicitly when you purposely mean to. Usually the `R` class you want is the one that is generated from the files in the `res` subdirectory when you first your project. You should remove the import statement for `android.R` and then compile your code. This should fix the problem. If not, please come back and update us on what the next problem is.